# US Intl keyboard layout without dead keys

Tags: keyboard-layout, 15.10, dead-keys

Is it possible to use the US International keyboard layout without dead keys? So, I'd like to get an `ä` when I type <kbd>Right Alt</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>, but `"a` when I type <kbd>"</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>.

Answer (score 9):

I just came around this thread having the same problem. I noticed in Ubuntu 16.04 the layout to achieve this is called `English (international with AltGr dead keys)`. So without the "US". This made me missing the option in the first place, so I hope this info is useful for others who want to achieve this particular behavior.

Answer (score 1):

The keyboard layout you want is English US International with AltGr Dead Keys. It types as a normal US keyboard generally, but you can hold down the right Alt key to get accented characters and dead keys.

(Or at least, normally that works. On my 16.04 installation, the dead keys only work outside of the X11 environment. :( But hopefully on yours everything works fine.)

Answer (score 0):

On installs of Ubuntu 14 and 16 atleast:

1. Go to taskbar --> Find `En` or something like that based on the keyboard you have chosen
2. Text Entry settings
3. add `English (international with AltGr dead keys)`

   - I wanted only euros so there is also a keyboard for that:
     `English (US, with Euro on 5)`

You can alter the keyboards at will with `Super(windows key) + space`

Answer (score 0):

I can further confirm the comment from @Mathias Kuhring using `Ubuntu 21.04`, `English (intl., with AltGr dead keys)` has the behavior or not needing to press `"` twice to type the character in.
And holding `ALT GR` then hitting `uiop` in that order results in `úíóö`.
This is the best middle ground for programmers who want an  English keyboard layout, but also write Latin or Germanic derived languages that need special characters.

Menu Option.

[image: English (intl., with AltGr dead keys) option]

Layout shown below.
[image: English (intl., with AltGr dead keys) layout]

Viel spaß !